# Always look up non-FQDN domains as .example.com?

Tags: ssh, dns

When I connect to the company OpenVPN they don't push their DNS to my computer, which means I have to type the FQDN for the hosts I e.g. SSH and HTTP to.

**Question**

Is it possible to configure my Linux desktop, so can do

```
ssh ss@serv
```

instead of

```
ssh ss@serv.example.com
```

?

There is only one domain, so incase the non-FQDN fails, it will always work, if just `example.com` is appended.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your resolv.conf:

```
search example.com
```

See resolv.conf(5) for details. If there is already a search line, just append `example.com` to its end

Answer (score 4):

Another approach (`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host *.example.com
 HostName %h
 USER user

Host *
 HostName %h.example.com
 USER user
```

This allows both forms:

```
ssh private.example.com # ssh user@private.example.com
ssh private             # ssh uesr@private.example.com
```

This really only works in the case where you are only connecting to `.example.com` hostnames (since `*` will match everything). I use a variation where I want to match only hostnames starting with `dev-`:

```
Host dev-*.example.com
 HostName %h
 USER user

Host dev-*
 HostName %h.example.com
 USER user
```